# react native: Flatlist overlap Scrollview scroll issue

Tags: reactjs, scrollview, native, flatlist

I do not speak English well. sorry.
I am working on mention function in react native.
Use flatlist for screen
The mention list is using ScreenView.
And the mention list is displayed as absolute as shown in the figure below.
however,
in android only,
when i scroll in the mention list, the flatlist below it scrolls.
Is there any solution to solve this?

[image: movie]

[image: style]